# Control.SetText doesn't change Text in ButtonRenderer

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to set multiple styles on the text in a Button with **ButtonRenderer**. On Android, styles have to be set with **Control.SetText()** but both the styles and the text are not applied.

It's weird that when I use the same code with **LabelRenderer** it works as expected.

Here is the **LabelRenderer**

```cs
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var ce = (CustomLabel) e.NewElement;
    var iconFont = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Context.Assets, "fa-solid-900.ttf");
    var spannableString = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    var spannable = new SpannableString("");
    spannableString.Append("Hello");
    spannableString.Append(spannable, new CustomTypefaceSpan(iconFont), SpanTypes.ExclusiveInclusive);
    Control.SetText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
}
```

The result from **LabelRenderer**

[image]

And here is the **ButtonRenderer**

```cs
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var ce = (AfButton) e.NewElement;
    var iconFont = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Context.Assets, "fa-solid-900.ttf");
    var spannableString = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    var spannable = new SpannableString(ce.IconText);
    spannableString.Append(spannable, new CustomTypefaceSpan(iconFont), SpanTypes.ExclusiveInclusive);
    spannableString.Append(ce.Text);
    Control.SetText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
}
```

The result from **ButtonRenderer** which shows the original text sets in the **Text** attribute.

[image]

Have anyone experienced this? Not sure if this a bug or not.

Thank you in advance for the answers.

Comment: I don't know much about this, but have you tried to change the order of the call to the "Append" method? That's one of the differences I noticed between the snippet that works and the one that doesn't.

Comment: @hfontanez changing the order doesn't affect the result. And yes it works on LabelRenderer but on ButtonRenderer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code

```
var iconFont = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Context.Assets, "xxx.ttf");
Control.Typeface = iconFont;
```

## Update

Set `SpanTypes` as `ExclusiveExclusive`

```
spannableString.Append(spannable, new CustomTypefaceSpan(iconFont), SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);
```

```
CustomTypefaceSpan customTypefaceSpan = new CustomTypefaceSpan(typeface);
var spannableString = new SpannableString("Hello");
spannableString.SetSpan(customTypefaceSpan, 0, spannableString.Length(), SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);
var span = new SpannableString("123456");
var spp = new SpannableStringBuilder();
spp.Append(spannableString);
spp.Append(span);
Control.SetText(spp, BufferType.Spannable);
```

Comment: This will apply the font to all the text on a button. I want to use FontAwesome with a specific part of the text. And the problem is I have accomplished this on LabelRenderer but ButtonRenderer

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still doesn't work. I tried to change just the text on the button with Control.SetText() but it didn't change.

Comment: ButtonRenderer.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with my environment. Thank you very much for the answer :)